# How do I put a space between two string items in Python

Tags: python

```
>>> item1="eggs"
>>> item2="sandwich"

>>> print(item1+item2)

>>> Output: eggssandwich
```

My main goal is to put a space between eggs and sandwich.

But i'm unsure on how to. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 20):

Use `.join()`:

```
print(" ".join([item1, item2]))
```

The default for `print`, however, is to put a space between arguments, so you could also do:

```
print(item1, item2)
```

Another way would be to use string formatting:

```
print("{} {}".format(item1, item2))
```

Or the old way:

```
print("%s %s" % (item1, item2))
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply!

```
'{} {}'.format(item1, item2)  # the most prefereable
```

or

```
'%s %s' % (item1, item2)
```

or if it is just print

```
print(item1, item2)
```

for dynamic count of elements you can use join(like in another answer in the tread).

Also you can read how to make really flexible formatting using format language from the first variant in official documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting

Update:
since f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6, it is also possible to use them:

```
f'{item1} {item2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the space!

```
print(item1 + ' ' + item2)
```

Comment: Works — but only if `item1` and `item2` are strings. `print(item1, item2)` doesn't have that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# works every time
print(item1, item2)
```

```py
# Only works if items 1 & 2 are strings.
print(item1 + " " + item2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three easy solutions to add a space.

Add a space in between, but as noted above this only works if both items are strings.

```
print("eggs" + " " + "sandwich")
```

Another simple solution would be to add a space to end of eggs or beginning of sandwich.

```
print("eggs " + "sandwich")
```

```
print("eggs" + " sandwich")
```

These will all return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways ;) :

```
print(f'Hello {firstname} {lastname}')
```

Or

```
print("Hello", firstname, lastname)
```

Or

```
print("Hello", firstname + ' ' + lastname)
```

Or

```
print(' '.join(["Hello", firstname , lastname]))
```

Or

```
[print(i, end=' ') for i in ["Hello", firstname, lastname]]
```